# find_or_create ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique rescue retry not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.4. I have a unique constraint on email column in my database.  If there's a race condition where one thread is creating a user and the other attempts to create at the same time a record not unique exception is raised.  I am trying to handle this exception by retrying so that when it retries it will find the customer during the SELECT in the find_or_create.

However, it does not seem to be working.  It runs out of retries and then re-raises the exception.

Here's what I was doing originally:

```
retries = 10
begin
  user = User.find_or_create_by(:email => email)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry unless (retries-=1).zero? 
  raise   
end
```

I then thought maybe the database connection was caching the SELECT query result causing it to think the user still does not exist and to continue to try to create it.  To fix that I tried using Model.uncached to disable query caching:

```
retries = 10
begin
  User.uncached do
    user = User.find_or_create_by(:email => email)
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry unless (retries-=1).zero? 
  raise   
end
```

`

This is also not working.  I'm not sure what else to do to fix this issue? Should I increase retries? Add a sleep delay between retries? Is there a better way to clear query cache (if that's the issue?)

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you reproducing this issue? Do you see it in production or in your test suite? Could you paste backtrace?

Comment: @John-S did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres there is an upsert (https://github.com/jesjos/active_record_upsert) gem that makes it really easy to add "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE" in a scenario like this. You would be able to replace your code with

```
User.upsert(email: email)
```

If you want to add or update other data in the same operation as part of the same upsert call, you should first specify that email is the unique key for the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  upsert_keys [:email]
end
```

Edit: To identify the problem with your approach try posting the relevant section of the log where we can see what SQL statements are being issued, including the transaction BEGIN/COMMITs.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is fixed in rails 6+ with the method `create_or_find_by`.

**Related PR:** https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31989

**Documentation:** https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Relation/create_or_find_by

> This is similar to #find_or_create_by, but avoids the problem of stale reads between the SELECT and the INSERT, as that method needs to first query the table, then attempt to insert a row if none is found.

**Warning:** There are several drawbacks to #create_or_find_by, so consider reading the doc for your use cases.